# Return to controller on FormRequest validation failure

Tags: laravel, laravel-formrequest

I'm trying to make an API with laravel and I'm trying to validate a few query parameters using FormRequest. My problem is that when the validator fails I still want to carry on using the controller as it does when it passes but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this. I know I have to override the failedValidation() function but I'm not sure what to override it with to get my desired result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thats not how validation works, when validation fails it is an indication that this request would fail, show your validation rules and when you want it to proceed, i think you need to make some nullable or similar fields and handle them after. What you are looking for is not gonna work and bad design.

Comment: If you accept the data no matter what is being sent, why bother validating in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. It was more a case of making sure the correct arguments were being passed. I suppose thinking about it the models will just return no results if the parameters are incorrect making this a pointless endeavour?

Comment: I suppose the idea would be that I want a default response if no parameters are set. There is a limit and a category, so the default would be 10 and all. However if the user has specified a particular parameter it would validate them before usage. I'm trying to keep up with best practices of keeping controllers clean and thought it would be a lot tidier. Maybe this logic would be better off in a service class?

Comment: You could use the [sometimes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#conditionally-adding-rules) validation rule, it will only validate the field if it is present in the data. You then could use your default value if it was not present.

Comment: That takes me back to my original question though is how to I get the form request class to return go to the controller opposed to a redirect? I know I can just use a validator in the controller but I didn't think that was the "correct" way to do it.

Comment: I managed to do what I want by using middleware in the end.